# real_connect(): MySQL server has gone away

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
Severity: Warning
Message: mysqli::real_connect(): MySQL server has gone away
Filename: mysqli/mysqli_driver.php
Line Number: 202
Backtrace:
File: /var/www/html/ctscms/application/third_party/MX/Loader.php Line: 107 Function: DB
File: /var/www/html/ctscms/index.p
```

Comment: reconnect the database, in CI use this in my_model or where you are using queries `$this->db->reconnect();`

Comment: Can you post the functions signaled in the backtrace? Anyway, [there](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/gone-away.html) is a detailed explaination of why that error can appear.

Comment: i paste this in my code but didn`t work because i m using HMVC approach

Comment: Also done 'pconnect' => TRUE, but i show some loader issues

Comment: also check php.ini, `mysqli.reconnect = On` is it on or off?

Comment: Improved formatting

Comment: The problem is solved i have too many connection with db so it make db little bit slow